# Subtracting specific values from column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to pandas library. 
I am working on a data set which looks like this :

[image]

suppose I want to subtract point score in the table. 
I want to subtract 100 if the score in **point score** column if the score is below 1000 
and subtract 200 if the score is above 1000 . How do I do this.

code :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("files/Soccer_Football Clubs Ranking.csv")
df.head(4)
```

Comment: please include your input as text not image and include your desired output as well.

Comment: Can you justify why you don't want to use numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
np.where(df['point score']<1000, df['point score']-100, df['point score']-200)
```

Demonstration:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'point score':[14001,200,1500,750]})
np.where(test['point score']<1000, test['point score']-100, test['point score']-200)
```

Output:

[image]

Based on the comment:

```
temp = test[test['point score']<1000]
temp=temp['point score']-100
temp2 = test[test['point score']>=1000]
temp2=temp2['point score']-200
temp.append(temp2)
```

Another solution:

```
out = []
for cell in test['point score']:
    if cell < 1000:
        out.append(cell-100)
    else:
        out.append(cell-200)
test['res'] = out
```

Fourth solution:

```
test['point score']-(test['point score']<1000).replace(False,200).replace(True,100)
```

Comment: We have to use  Numpy for this. Can't we do this only in pandas

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: Can you share the code for that.

Comment: Please look at the answer.

Comment: I provided another way in the answer.

Comment: thanks, I was going to ask another question but the last approach sorted that out. The last approach is best I guess cause it gives more flexibility.

Comment: Why only in pandas? There is no pandas without numpy, it makes no sense to refrain oneself to use numpy... The second approach is **not** better as it is not vectorized (will be slower)

Comment: yeah second is not a good approach but third approach is the best one. If you want to change values in range say like.. subtract 200 if the values is between 1000 and 2000 it will be easier with the last approach. It may be complicated to perform such in numpy.

Comment: With numpy you can use nested conditioning for this purpose.

Comment: No the last approach is terrible, there is no reason not to use vectorial code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve vectorial code without explicitly using numpy (although numpy is used by pandas anyways), and keeping vectorial code:

```
# example 1
df['map'] = df['point score'] - df['point score'].gt(1000).map({True: 200, False: 100})

# example 2, multiple criteria
# -100 below 1000, -200 below 2000, -300 above 3000
df['cut'] = df['point score'] - pd.cut(df['point score'], bins=[0,1000,2000,float('inf')], labels=[100, 200, 300]).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   point score   map   cut
0          800   700   700
1          900   800   800
2         1000   900   900
3         2000  1800  1800
4         3000  2800  2700
```